# Android open an EditText link using a button

Tags: java, android, jquery, url, android-intent

I've searched around allot on how to open a link that you have entered in an input field (`EditText`) which will open when you press a button.
But sadly, I've only found this.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

What I am aiming for is something similar to this, I want to have a default link already stated in the code however when you enter text into the input field, it will add to the default link. For example something like this, default link is: http://www.google.com/ But when I enter "design" into the input field (`EditText`) and hit the button it will make it: http://www.google.com/design and it'll open the link as that.

How can I achieve this? I'm new to programming and I've taken a look at the AOSP browser code but it's far too complex for me to understand. Hopefully someone could explain how I can achieve something like this, please don't get angry at me because I have seen many new users getting bashed upon asking simple things.

Thanks.

Comment: @LoopyLoo: I prepared a detailed code for you. lease check if that will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a detailed code as per your requirement. Please let me know if you find any problem:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LinkActivity extends Activity {

    EditText txtLink;
    Button btnOpenLink;
    String defaultLink;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_link);

        defaultLink = "http://www.google.com";

        txtLink = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLink);
        btnOpenLink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOpenLink);
        btnOpenLink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String page = txtLink.getText().toString();
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(page)){
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(defaultLink+"/"+page);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(LinkActivity.this, "Please enter page on editText!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Your XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextLink"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOpenLink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Open Link" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Then you can write it or suggest me here or edit my reply. There was no need to down vote secretly without any comment. As LoopyLoo already said he's new to Android so it's better to give him a detailed code. Let him decide, why you down voted secretly!!

Comment: Leave it. You already did a cheap work here by doing down vote and I don't want to waste both of us time any  more on it.